# How to apply correct construct to CloudFrontWebDistribution class

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I am having an issue with creating an `CloudFrontWebDistribution` object with `aws-cdk v1.7`. The compiler doesn't seem to be happy about the construct I passed in.

```
import { Stack, StackProps, Construct, App } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { CloudFrontWebDistribution } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront';

export class MyCloudFrontStack extends Stack {

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, CloudFrontStackParameters, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const env = parameters.environment.toLowerCase();
        const webDistributionConfigs = { // configurations here... };
        this.cloudFrontWebDistrubtion = new CloudFrontWebDistribution(scope, id, webDistributionConfigs); // typescript complaining about the scope variable
    }
}
```

The typescript compiler then complains about the `scope` variable passed into the `CloudFrontWebDistribution` constructor.

> Argument of type
>   'import("c:/Users/me/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct").Construct'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'import("c:/Users/me/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct").Construct'.   Types of property 'node' are incompatible.
>       Property '_defaultChild' is missing in type 'import("c:/Users/me/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct").ConstructNode'
>   but required in type
>   'import("c:/Users/me/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda/node_modules/@aws-cdk/core/lib/construct").ConstructNode'.ts(2345)
>   construct.d.ts(61, 13): '_defaultChild' is declared here.

Is it because I use the type incorrectly here? Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that all your `@aws-cdk/...` deps are using v1.7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this issue.

```
import { Stack, StackProps, Construct, App } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { CloudFrontWebDistribution } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront';

export class MyCloudFrontStack extends Stack {

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, CloudFrontStackParameters, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const env = parameters.environment.toLowerCase();
        const webDistributionConfigs = { // configurations here... };
        this.cloudFrontWebDistrubtion = new CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, id, webDistributionConfigs); 
    }
}
```

The key here is to use `this` keyword and pass it in as the first argument in the `new CloudFrontWebDistribution(...)` constructor. I think this is to tell the CDK to create the CloudFront web distribution for the current stack only, i.e. `MyCloudFrontStack`, not the parent stack (the `scope` variable).

Also, by explicitly adding dependencies in `package.json` and making sure they are on the same version, it'd help avoid possible version conflicts for packages.

Comment: I know this is an old one, but when i try to pass 'this', its throwing an error that it doesnt recognize stack. TS2345: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'.  Type 'MyStack' is not assignable to type 'Construct'. Any suggestion?